# Querying a MySQL result in Python instead running a new call against the database

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the sake of simplicity, I have queried a bunch of tables from a MysSQL database to have a comprehensive capture of student data in a school, including their daily attendance (returns 15,000 rows with dates and biographical information).  I want to derive multiple reports (different departments have different KPIs) without having to constantly re-query the database for the different parameters needed by each report.

I understand I can use a Panda query (ie. pd.read_sql) as well as convert the return data from a SQL execute command into a Panda dataframe; I would ask if it is possible to use sql commands to refine a returned data set as I am already familiar with sql commands to derive/extrapolate values without a new execute to the Mysql database.  I know to use dataframe for filtering and flashing different views of data but I am not knowledgeable about its ability to transform/recalculate the data.

Excuse my example if my terms are imprecise/nonsensical:

I run a qs.execute(sql statement) against a database and output my first report.  Rather than run the original retrieval against the database with a slight or major tweak (transform calendar date into weekday values and report certain observed patters or create summary crosstab tables), I would rather query the original returned Python object (dictionary/list??) and create the new flavor of the same report and then keep going.  I would even be interested in creating joins between two returned data collections/sets or embedding the data set in a new sql statement that runs 'in memory' rather than a new call to the database.

What is generally the best practices?

Comment: You can do this if you use an ORM like SQLAlchemy. You can't do it with the basic MySQL Connector.

Comment: You should rather use a proper BI solution like power BI or Tableau than trying to reinvent the wheel! If you want a python-based solution, then look into frameworks like dash.

Comment: If you want to use pandas and write everything yourself, then you need to use pandas' API to perform filtering or joining or you need to use a library like panasql that enables you to run sql-like queries on pandas dataframes.